# Using CMake to include/link libraries installed with conda (mamba)

Tags: c++, cmake, conda

I'm working on a machine where I am unable to install to /usr/local, and so am exploring using conda environments instead.  My project has 3 dependencies:  `cspice`, `tbb`, and `zstd`.  I have installed each of these using conda, and have verified that the binaries are in:

- `~/mamba_envs/my_env/lib/cspice.a`
- `~/mamba_envs/my_env/lib/libtbb.so`
- `~/mamba_envs/my_env/bin/libzstd.so`

while the headers are in:

- `~/mamba_envs/my_env/include/cspice/SpiceUsr.h`
- `~/mamba_envs/my_env/include/oneapi/tbb.h`
- `~/mamba_envs/my_env/include/zstd.h`

When I go to compile though, I get errors such as:

```
fatal error: oneapi/tbb.h: No such file or directory
```

It would appear to me that it is still looking either in /usr/local/include, or somewhere else, and not in the conda environment. My project has the following structure:

```
project/
   | - external/
   | - include/
   | - lib/
   |   | - CMakeLists.txt
   |   | - *.cpp
   | - src/
   |   | - CMakeLists.txt
   |   | - *.cpp
   | - CMakeLists.txt
```

The `lib/` directory is what requires the dependencies.  And so I attempted to add to `lib/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(~/mamba_envs/my_env/include)
```

However this does not do anything.

What would I need to do to both include the proper headers and link what is needed?  It appears as though conda (mamba) is installing everything I'd need, but I am unsure on how to use CMake to look in the correct places.

I have also tried using: `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$CONDA_PREFIX`, in combination with adding:

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
```

however it still cannot find `tbb.h`.

### EDIT

If I modify the header that uses `#include <oneapi/tbb.h>` to be `#include </home/cgnam/mamba_envs/my_env/include/oneapi/tbb.h>` it then gives me an error from within that file:

```
/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/my_env/include/oneapi/tbb.h:28:10: fatal error: oneapi/tbb/blocked_range.h: No such file or directory
   28 | #include "oneapi/tbb/blocked_range.h"
```

Further, when I print out `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` it correctly shows `/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/my_env/`.  I am at a total loss as to what I am missing.

### Edit 2

I've also found that if I add `include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/oneapi)` to my CMakeLists.txt, and change the `#include <oneapi/tbb.h>` to `#include <tbb.h>` it correctly finds the file, but then throws the same error as in my first edit:

```
/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/my_env/include/oneapi/tbb.h:28:10: fatal error: oneapi/tbb/blocked_range.h: No such file or directory
   28 | #include "oneapi/tbb/blocked_range.h"
```

So the `include_directories()` command is working, but for some reason when I use `include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)` it cannot find the `oneapi/tbb.h` which is in that directory.

Comment: It seems weird to use `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` inside a CMakeLists.txt since it can be overriden by the `--prefix` option of the command-line install subcommand. The thing you're using it _for_ also seems a weird thing to use it for. Are you sure [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) isn't what you're looking for?